# Unable to build sln because of v11.0.0.0 Microsoft.TeamFoundation reference error

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2013, tfs, sln-file

I am unable to build .sln in VS2010. I have VS2013 installed aswell

Have referenced dlls from "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0 "references

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this NuGet package instead:

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick response. Could you please tell me how to refer those new dlls, i m unable to find "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0"

Comment: thanks for the link. i was able to install the nuget package. However while debugging its still throwing the exception "Could not load type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.Internal.RegistryAccessMask' from assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'."

Comment: @prashanthkr08, what's your build log?